# What is $ x^{23^{33}}\pmod{77}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My approach for this question is to use Chinese remainders theorem. First to calculate $ x^{23^{33}}\bmod{7} $and then $ x^{23^{33}}\bmod {11}$. However, I don't know how to solve $ x^{23^{33}}\bmod 7$.

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset mathematics. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  in order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: Exponentiation is not associative.  Do you mean $13^{23^{33}}$ or $\left(13^{23}\right)^{33}$?

Comment: I mean the first one

Comment: What is $x$? Is it some specific integer or just a variable. If it's a variable I think the modulo operation does not affect the expression in question.

Comment: Please don't change your question after answers have been posted.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I now understood the mismatch between question and answers. I think such edits should be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Observe that $23^{33}$ is odd, and that:

$$13^{2k} \equiv (-1)^{k} \mod 7$$

For any integer $k$.

And for any other possibility, we have that:

$$13^j \equiv 6 \equiv -1\mod 7$$

for any odd $j$, observe that, by definition, $7 | 6 - (-1)$.

Comment: To get the parenthetical "mod", use `\pmod{7}` instead of `\mod 7`: `$13^{2k}\equiv (-1)^k\pmod{7}$` gives $13^{2k}\equiv (-1)^k\pmod{7}$.  To get the binary mod operator, use `\bmod` (which does not include the awkward extra spacing: compare `$-1\mod 7$`: $-1 \mod 7$, with `$-1\bmod 7$`: $-1\bmod 7$.

Comment: Thanks, I will make use of them from now on.

Comment: ones for binary operation mod, and ones for relational mod.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try using the [Carmichael reduced totient $\lambda$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), iterated for the second exponent, to find a simpler expression:

$$ x^{\large 23^{\Large 33}} \equiv x^{\large (23^{\Large 33\bmod \lambda(\lambda(77))} \bmod \lambda(77))}\bmod 77$$

$\lambda(77)=\text{lcm}(\lambda(7),\lambda(11))=\text{lcm}(6,10) = 30$
$\lambda(30)=\text{lcm}(\lambda(2),\lambda(3),\lambda(5)) = 4$

So we don't get anything out of the first exponent reduction, but the second gives us $33\equiv 1 \bmod 4$. Reducing an exponent to $1$ is sometimes a little problematic but here $23$ is prime and large enough not to be an issue so we can say (for $x\in \Bbb N$):

$$x^{\large 23^{\Large 33}} \equiv x^{23}\bmod 77$$

Comment: Carmichael only applies if $x$ is coprime to $77$ so the argument is incomplete (or incorrect). In any case, it is a dupe.

Comment: No Bill, Carmichael applies all the time as the minimum & universal cycle length. Some care may need to be applied when reducing to low exponent values is the only caveat, but there are no prime powers of exponent over $23$ in $77$. Is this a dupe? I'm not sure I've seen this kind of question with a variable base.

Comment: Please *precisely* state the (Carmichael) Theorem that you are implicitly applying above.  The most common version only applies when $x$ is coprime to the modulus. In a question at this level one should always be more precise, and justify such claims by linking to proofs, since there are frequently oversights in such matters.

Answer (score 0):

A consequence of [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) is that when you reduce $a^b$ modulo $n$ where $a$ and $n$ are coprime, you can reduce the exponent $b$ modulo $\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ is Eulers totient function:
$$
b\equiv c \pmod{\varphi(n)} \quad\Longrightarrow\quad a^b \equiv a^c \pmod{n}.
$$
You can apply that recursively to reduce towers of powers.

Comment: But this does not apply in the OPs case since $x$ is not assumed coprime to $77\  $ (after edit)

Comment: @BillDubuque Right, … When I answered it was $13$ instead of $x$.